# GCC compilation with nostdlib flag for Aarch64 platform

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, system-calls, arm64

I am trying to compile binary with nostdlib flag on Aarch64 platform.

I've dealt successfully with it on x86-64 platform this way:

```
    void _start() {

    /* main body of program: call main(), etc */

    /* exit system call */
    asm("movl $1,%eax;"
        "xorl %ebx,%ebx;"
        "int  $0x80"
    );
}
```

Is there any analogue to do the same thing on aarch64 platform?(specifically system exit call)

Comment: Yes. It will likely be an `svc` instruction but the exact details depend on your OS.

Answer (score 3):

The example hereafter should work on an aarch64-linux-gnu system - It does work using running qemu-aarch64 3.0 on my x86_64 linux system.

The most concise/loosely coupled source of information for learning purpose would be [musl-libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/) source code in my humble opinion:

- [syscall_arch.h](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/arch/aarch64/syscall_arch.h) does contain the _syscall functions to be used depending on the number of arguments required by a given syscall,
- [syscall.h](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/arch/aarch64/bits/syscall.h.in).in does contain defines for all system calls.

We should then use:

```
static inline long __syscall1(long n, long a)
{
    register long x8 __asm__("x8") = n;
    register long x0 __asm__("x0") = a;
    __asm_syscall("r"(x8), "0"(x0));
}
```

and __NR_exit:

```
#define __NR_exit 93
#define __NR_exit_group 94
```

A basic example in C would be syscall-exit.c:

```
#include "syscall_arch.h"
#include "syscall.h.in"

int main(void)
{
   // exiting with return code 1.
    __syscall1(__NR_exit, 1);

   // we should have exited.
   for (;;);
}
```

Compiling/executing/checking return code:

```
/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -static -O0 -o exit-syscall exit-syscall.c
qemu-aarch64 exit-syscall
echo $?
1
```

A close look at the generated code for main() and __syscall1() using:

```
/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump  -D exit-syscall > exit-syscall.lst
```

Would look like:

```
0000000000400554 <main>:
400554:   a9bf7bfd    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
400558:   910003fd    mov x29, sp
40055c:   d2800021    mov x1, #0x1                    // #1
400560:   d2800ba0    mov x0, #0x5d                   // #93
400564:   97fffff4    bl  400534 <__syscall1>


0000000000400534 <__syscall1>:
400534:   d10043ff    sub sp, sp, #0x10
400538:   f90007e0    str x0, [sp, #8]
40053c:   f90003e1    str x1, [sp]
400540:   f94007e8    ldr x8, [sp, #8]
400544:   f94003e0    ldr x0, [sp]
400548:   d4000001    svc #0x0
40054c:   910043ff    add sp, sp, #0x10
400550:   d65f03c0    ret
```

See document "[Procedure Call Standard for the ARM 64-bit Architecture(AArch64)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0055b/IHI0055B_aapcs64.pdf)" for more information.

Therefore, an Aarch64 equivalent of your x86_64 code would be exit-asm.c :

```
void main(void) {

    /* exit system call  - calling NR_exit with 1 as the return code*/
    asm("mov x0, #1;"
        "mov x8, #93;"
        "svc #0x0;"
    );

    for (;;);
}


/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -static -o example example.c 
qemu-aarch64 example
echo $?
1
```

Please note that glibc implementation of exit() does call __NR_exit_group prior to call __NR_exit.